# Updating the amount of text displayed based on input range

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm writing a simple javascript library to update the amount of text (i.e. number of words) displayed in a `section` element based on the HTML5 input range slider.

I have a version that works for one single `p` element, but not for multiple `p` elements within a `section`.

HTML

```
<section>
  <p>Text example:</p>

  <section data-range="true">
    <input type="range">
      <p>Contemporary web applications utilize a Representational State Transfer (REST) software architectural schema through the combination of front and back-end model-view-controller (MVC) and routing frameworks. The implementation of a MVC framework on the front-end helps to create the effect of a seamless single page application where data is asynchronously processed by the server, and updated in the view.</p>

      <p>The controller on the front-end is responsible for communicating with the server via HTTP requests. Data objects on the front-end are usually encapsulated in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) and asynchronously sent to the server for performing various logic, or RESTful operations identified by Uniform Resource Identifiers (URIs) in HTTP requests.</p>
  </section>
</section>
```

JS

```
/*  updateInnerText
*   Update inner text based on range section
*   @param the event elemenet (range input)
*   @param range value, number of words to display
*/
function updateInnerText(el, length) {
    var paragraphs = [];

    for (var p = 0; p < numParagraphs; p++) {
        var ob = {};
        ob['text'] = el.srcElement.parentNode.children[p + 1].attributes["data-text"].value;
        ob['numWords'] = el.srcElement.parentNode.children[p + 1].attributes["data-text"].value.split(' ').length;
        paragraphs.push(ob);
    }
    // update on the DOM
    for (var x = numParagraphs; x >= 0; x--) {
        var diff = fullText.split(' ').length - length;
        diff = +diff + +length; 
        el.srcElement.parentNode.children[x].innerHTML = paragraphs[x - 1]['text'].substring(0, diff);
    }
}
```

Update:

Here is a [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/wohodo/3/edit?html,js,output) with the original working version.

Here is an updated [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/qihariyala/edit?js,output) trying multiple paragraphs.

Comment: `el` is actually the event object (you're accessing the event element via `el.srcElement`.)  A more standard way to access the element is [`.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

Comment: I've included an updated JSbin

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modified version of your function that works recursively over an element and its subtree.  It removes text nodes that are beyond the word count (splitting the border text node if necessary.)

This updated [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/fazolivoka/1/edit?js,output) should do what you want.

```
// updateInnerText :: Event, Number -> undefined
function updateInnerText(el, length) {
    var curNode        = null,
        curWords       = [],
        nodesToRemove  = [],
        remainingWords = length,
        wordsSoFar     = 0,
        walker         = document.createTreeWalker(el, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);

    while (curNode = walker.nextNode()) {
        curWords       = getWords(curNode.textContent);
        remainingWords = length - wordsSoFar;

        if (remainingWords <= 0) {
            nodesToRemove.push(curNode);
        } else if (remainingWords >= curWords.length) {
            wordsSoFar += curWords.length;
        } else {
            wordsSoFar = length;
            nodesToRemove.push(curNode.splitText(remainingWordsCharCount()));
        }
        curNode = walker.nextNode();
    }

    nodesToRemove.forEach(function (n) { n.remove(); });

    // getWords :: String -> [String]
    function getWords(text) {
        return text.split(/\s+/ig)
                   .map(function (s) { return s.trim(); })
                   .filter(Boolean);
    }

    // remainingWordsCharCount :: undefined -> Number
    function remainingWordsCharCount() {
        return curWords.slice(0, remainingWords).join(' ').length;
    }
}
```